# How to merge Git pushed copy of branch

Tags: git

I did this:

```
cd /repo1
git clone <remote-repo>
git checkout -b mynewbranch
<edit1>
git add
git commit
<edit2>
git add
git commit

cd /repo2
git clone <remote-repo>

cd /repo1
git checkout master
git merge mynewbranch
# messages
# All merged Ok.

git checkout mynewbranch
git push /repo2 mynewbranch:mynewbranch

cd /repo2
git branch
* master
  mynewbranch
git merge mynewbranch
# Tons of merge conflict errors
```

Directories repo1 and repo2 have clones of the exact same version and branch of code.  `git branch -r` says the same thing in both directories as well.

Merging my branch in repo1 works perfectly.  But when I push that branch to repo2 and try the same merge, I get merge conflicts.

What am I missing?  Can this be done correctly?

Comment: In both cases, `git branch -r` says the same thing, the name of the remote-repo ref.